# Vue getter/setter emitting number turns into infinite loop when inputting decimals

Tags: javascript, vue.js, numbers, decimal

I have an input component that has some validation and I reuse this in many different places and other calculations use the output from this component. The issue I am having is that I need this component to accept any value, from 100000 to .00000001

I am using a getter/setter function and maybe this is too much for it but I have this architecture in other component and it's working fine but one takes large numbers and one takes small numbers. This takes both and freaks out!

Here is the code:

```
 computed: {
  theValue:{
    //display whole numbers to the user
    get(){
      return this.value;
    },
    // set the decimal into the application
    set(update){
      if(isNaN(update)){
        console.log(typeof(update));
      } else {
        this.$emit("input", parseFloat(update));

      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried `Number(update)` as well and it does the same thing, it goes into an infinite loop about `NaN` not being a number and iterates at around 100 calculations per second and I have to close the browser tab using the task manager. Fun. It will output a string if I don't try to coerce the datatype which is undesirable.

So how can I get this to emit a number, it emits a string just fine but my calculations are adding strings to numbers, and I'm sure you know that doesn't end well. I would like to keep things clean and contain this logic in this component without having to put `Number()` all over the application.

Any help would be appreciated. Please do not link back to another post regarding Javascript and Numbers, I would like help with a solution not a reference to a reference.

Here is the whole component.

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <label>{{name}}</label>
    <ValidationProvider
      :rules="rules"
      v-slot="{ errors }"
      :name="fieldName"
    >

      <input
        class="form-control"
        v-model="theValue"
        type="number"
      />

      <span class="val-error-span">
        {{ errors[0] }}
      </span>

    </ValidationProvider>
  </div>
</template>
​
<script lang="js">
  import Vue from 'vue';
  export default {
    name: 'PercentInput',
    model: {
      prop: 'value',
      event: 'input'
    },
    props: [
      'value',
      'name',
      'fieldName',
      'rules'
    ],
    data(){
      return{
      }
    },
    computed: {
      theValue:{
        //display whole numbers to the user
        get(){
          return this.value;
        },
        // set the decimal into the application
        set(update){
          if(isNaN(update)){
            console.log(typeof(update));
          } else {
            this.$emit("input", parseFloat(update));

          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<style>


</style>
```

Comment: Its very possible the reason its a loop is your getter is returning the getter and not the value? so it returns itself, which returns itself and so on. This creates an infinite loop. Can I see where you are calling this getter?

Comment: No it only happens when I have `Number(update)` when I just pass `update` it works fine, but passes a string.

Comment: an easy way in javascript to turn a string to a number is to add a +

its kinda a hack but it works.

`this.$emit("input", +update)`

Comment: If I do that it only shows whole numbers, it removes decimals.

Comment: Keep in mind this updates on every input typed...

Comment: Interesting, Im not sure why that removes the decimal places. You can test this out with.`console.log(+'1.05')

Comment: if you just go to the console  and type in `console.log(+'.0000');` you get `0` I'm assuming this is why it is a string, maybe I have to try to validate `onBlur` or something. Otherwise I'd have to regex this thing or something.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with your code above. Can you provide a reproducible example in codesandbox?